# Create Customer w/ simple Stripe Checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

My aim to to verify a users card information and store that info in a customer object.

I run a pay-upon delivery service and am building a hack to protect against fake orders (we can charge people via the strip dashboard if they place false orders or don't show up).

A full stripe integration is the long term goal, but I need something ASAP. I've read (re-read) the the docs but am having trouble.

The simple stripe checkout works great, but I am clueless about how to create a customer from there.

Script:

```
    <form action="/charge" method="POST">
      <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="TEST KEY"
        data-image="/square-image.png"
        data-name="Food Bazooka"
        data-description="Customer Verification. No charges :)"
        data-panel-label="Confirm and Verify"
        data-label="Confirm">
      </script>


    </form>
```

Any feedback or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the embedded form, where as you need to use custom forms and some server side code.

You would need first create a single use token which represents a customer card from your form
(Assuming your form contains credit card number, expiry date etc...)

Taken from the docs:

**Form markup:**

```
<form action="/customer" method="POST" id="payment-form">
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

This essentially takes your form, and adds a hidden field called `stripeToken` before submitting

Notice the form action is /customer

I see you're using Ruby On Rails from your tag - so you would need to handle the customer POST with a controller

This is what you'll need to do:
https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later

```
# Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
# See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_X9S2nHIxFy399uoNvakwJYSn"

# Get the credit card details submitted by the form
# notice stripeToken - this is the hidden field 
token = params[:stripeToken]

# Create a Customer
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :card => token,
  :description => "payinguser@example.com"
)

# Charge the Customer instead of the card
# ** I have commented this block out, as you say you do not want to charge the customer
# Stripe::Charge.create(
    # :amount => 1000, # incents 
    # :currency => "gbp",
    # :customer => customer.id
# )

# Save the customer ID in your database so you can use it later
save_stripe_customer_id(user, customer.id)
```